# PHP start with <? - 500 Server error - T_OPEN_TAG

Tags: php

I migrated a php website to a new server.

```
 Old PHP Version -> 5.2
 New PHP Version -> 5.5
```

When a script contains the T_OPEN_TAG

```
<?
```

instead of

```
<?php
```

the server is sending a 500 Server error. How is it possible to allow that php could start with

```
<?
```

thank you

Comment: Read this once before applying it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in php.ini

And restart your Apache server.

Comment: ahh, thank you very much. phpinfo is saying: short_open_tag = Off. Will test it in a couple of minutes and mark it as fixed.

Comment: Read this once before applying it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: Thank you. There is also a option in Plesk under PHP Settings to allow short_open_tags